# Insert json data in table with Asyncpg using "executemany"

Tags: python, postgresql, asyncpg

I want to insert with Asyncpg some json data in a table (2 columns:  id , cluster_json).   I want to use  the "executemany" function to speedup  the insert process.

my code:

```py
async def main():

    conn = await asyncpg.connect('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres')
    statement = '''INSERT INTO cluster(cluster_json) VALUES($1) '''
    await conn.executemany(statement, [{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null},
                                       {"name":"John1", "age":31, "car":null}'])

    await conn.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

but I get the following error :

```
asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input in executemany() argument sequence element #0: expected a sequence, got dict
```

I tryied to pass the dictionaries as str. also got a bug.

The error  message is clear , the code the pretty similar to the one in the documentation,
expect that I want insert  json data .   Unfortunately, I  don't see what I am missing.
Does someone  spot the issue  / help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to double nest your JSON-blob in a list. The first list is for each row you want to insert. The second list is for each argument you want to pass to the SQL statement. `asyncpg` doesn't try parse your SQL statement. So it doesn't know you are only using one argument. So it needs you to hold it's hand a little and give a list of all the arguments for the statement, even if that list only has one element.

```py
await conn.executemany(
    statement,
    [   # for first execution of statement 
        [   # first argument (i.e. $1) of first execution of statement
            '{"name":"John", "age":30, "car": null}',
        ],
        # for second execution of statement 
        [   # first argument (i.e. $1) of second execution of statement
            '{"name":"John1", "age":31, "car": null}',
        ],
    ]
)
```

Comment: Nice. This saved me hours of head banging... Thanks

Comment: once stored in Postgres12, I get all double quotes " preceded by escape \, is this normal behaviour?